# why my uialeartview alway change position when rotage

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, uialertview, screen-rotation

My uialeartview code.
when it show in Landscape or Portrait it ok but when 
change Portrait to Landscape or Landscape to Portrait

it will always move up not in center of window like before

how can i make it it center of window when rotage.

```
UIAlertView *over; 
            over=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Game over" 
                                                          message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your score : %d\n\n\n",score]   
                                                         delegate:self 
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [over show];

            UITextField *nameinputfiled=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(11, 80, over.frame.size.width-50, 31)];
            nameinputfiled.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
            [over addSubview:nameinputfiled];
[over release];
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add the `UIAlertView` as a subView, just use `[over show]` and don't forget to release it afterwards.

Comment: try commenting the adding of the `UITextField` - does it still change the position?

Comment: No if i comment the add textfield line the position does not change like i want but i need text field in it.

Comment: try to set a fixed width for the `UITextField` frame, e.g. `CGRectMake(12,80,260,31)`. Remember that you possibly have to use a `CGAffineTransform` when showing the keyboard